# Items of LongListMultiSelector horizontally

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

For several hours I have tried to change my LongListMultiSelector from WP toolkit to show its items horizontally like on the screenshot below (from Panorama Sample).

[image: http://i.imgur.com/HGHPOsq.png]

I even tried with changing its Template but with no possitive effects.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: So how about you actually show us what you've tried?

Comment: I do not certainly know what to show you since only thing I achieved is items were horizontal but in 1 row only.

You know I want to have exactly the same effect what standard LongListMultiSelector provides but in horizontal way.

I don't even know if is it possible because I saw some questions on StackOverflow connected with ListListSelector from which I understood that it's only possible with ListBox (but here I will lost my desired behaviour - multiselecting.

Of course then I also won't be able to show the list of elements in the way I need. Simple, horizontal StackPanel isn't what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. I finally did it. If somebody will have the same problem here is my solution.

I always try to avoid solving layout problems in WP by code behind way but exceptionally I did it this way.

My XAML:

```
<Grid Margin="10 -30 0 0" Name="GridWithLLMS">
    <toolkit:LongListMultiSelector LayoutMode="Grid"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
        GridCellSize="255,190"
        toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True"
        EnforceIsSelectionEnabled="True"
        Margin="0"
    />
</Grid>
```

My code:

```
public AddNewTrainingPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    SetWidthOfGridWithExercisesDependingOnQuantityOfItems();
    DataContext = App.Db;
}

private void SetWidthOfGridWithExercisesDependingOnQuantityOfItems()
{
    ExercisesListGrid.Width = ((App.Db.Items.Count / 3) + 1) * 270;
}
```

Where:

- `3` is number of rows I want to have
- `255` is width of 1 **LongListMultiSelectorItem** (+ potential margin width)

Of course I assume my **LongListMultiSelector's** items won't change. If you want to make it working with dynamic collection of elements you should bind the width of LongListMultiSelector to the property with quantity of your collection's items in your ViewModel

Answer (score 1):

Check this out

http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/wp7-longlistselector-in-depth--part2-data-binding-scenarios

The code snippet in the last will help.

```
<toolkit:LongListSelector.GroupItemsPanel>
   <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <toolkit:WrapPanel/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
 </toolkit:LongListSelector.GroupItemsPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  
Unfortunately I use WP8 and the article you sent is about WP7. I don't know about distinctions between WP7 and WP8 but:  

1. In WP8 I use `<phone:>` instead of `<toolkit:>` to use LongListSelector.  
2. To Edit Template of LongListMultiSelector from **toolkit** I need to edit LongListSelector which is inside LongListMultiSelector  
I don't have access to the property `GroupItemsPanel` of LongListSelector from `<phone:>`